# SQL Join statement returning incorrect table field data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, left-join, right-join

I have two tables in SQL that I am trying to join. The operation is successful, however the `Location` field in the resultset is pulling data from the incorrect table.

Both tables in the JOIN statement have a field named `location` and the resultset is supposed to pull from the `RDet` table (i.e RDet.location). But the resultset data shows that it is pulling from the `RDoc` table as if I specified `RDoc.location`.

```
   SELECT RDoc.[orderno],
          RDoc.[contact],
          RDet.location,
          RDoc.[currdate] as 'Date_Scanned',
          RDet.[oldequip#],
          RDet.[equip#]
   FROM [dbo].[RCSCDocumentDetail] as RDet 
        JOIN [dbo].[RCSCDocument] as RDoc ON RDet.[docheaderid] = RDoc.[id]
```

---

```
RCSCDocumentDetail Table
id  |docheaderid |description     |mfg |model  |equip# |serial# |rate |oldequip# |location
1201 1030         BATTERY/36V      DEK          DB41718 2351LT   0     DB41718    29.995437,-95.4876791
```

---

```
RCSCDocument Table
id  |orderno |ordertype |signimage         |contact  |HadSigned |location               |currdate               |kbranch
1030 612991   P          /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ MARK/VLAD 1          11.02499700,76.95863308 2015-12-09 05:42:37.000 100
```

---

```
    Desired Result Set
    RDoc.[orderno]|RDoc.[contact]| RDet.location           |RDoc.[currdate]         |RDet.oldequip#]|RDet.[equip#]
    612991         MARK/VLAD       29.995437,-95.4876791    2015-12-09 05:42:37.000  DB41718         DB41718
```

Comment: As posted this doesn't make a lot of sense. Do you need to add Location as another predicate in your join?

Comment: As Sean noted,try adding predicate,You may need to add sample data as well expected output and current output for some one to understand better

Comment: little confusing , join seems fine, so we need sample data and sample output then only we can identify what is your goal

Comment: I have added the sample data as requested.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you could migrate your sample data to something consumable. sqlfiddle.com would be a good option for this.